# ValueError: GpuCorrMM images and kernel must have the same stack size

Tags: python, theano, keras, gpuimage

My input data shape is [n, 3, 64, 64]

I got this after run the code on Stampede.

```
Using Theano backend.
Using gpu device 0: Tesla K20m (CNMeM is disabled, cuDNN not available)
ValueError: GpuCorrMM images and kernel must have the same stack size

Apply node that caused the error: GpuCorrMM{half, (1, 1)}(GpuContiguous.0, GpuContiguous.0)
Toposort index: 115
Inputs types: [CudaNdarrayType(float32, 4D), CudaNdarrayType(float32, 4D)]
Inputs shapes: [(32, 8, 16, 1024), (256, 512, 5, 5)]
Inputs strides: [(131072, 16384, 1024, 1), (12800, 25, 5, 1)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown']
Outputs clients: [[GpuElemwise{Add}[(0, 0)](GpuCorrMM{half, (1, 1)}.0, GpuReshape{4}.0)]]
```

what's going on with the code and how to solve this problem? Thanks

My code:

```
g_input = Input(shape=(100,))

generator = Sequential()
generator.add(Dense(1024 * 4 * 4, input_shape=(100,)))
generator.add(BatchNormalization(mode=2))
generator.add(Activation('relu'))
generator.add(Reshape([1024, 4, 4]))

generator.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), dim_ordering='th'))
generator.add(Convolution2D(512, 5, 5, border_mode='same', dim_ordering='th'))
generator.add(BatchNormalization(mode=2))
generator.add(Activation('relu'))

generator.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), dim_ordering='th'))
generator.add(Convolution2D(256, 5, 5, border_mode='same', dim_ordering='th'))
generator.add(BatchNormalization(mode=2))
generator.add(Activation('relu'))

generator.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), dim_ordering='th'))
generator.add(Convolution2D(128, 5, 5, border_mode='same', dim_ordering='th'))
generator.add(BatchNormalization(mode=2))
generator.add(Activation('relu'))

generator.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), dim_ordering='th'))
generator.add(Convolution2D(64, 5, 5, border_mode='same', dim_ordering='th'))
generator.add(BatchNormalization(mode=2))
generator.add(Activation('relu'))

generator.add(Convolution2D(3, 5, 5, border_mode='same', dim_ordering='th'))
generator.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

generator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5))
generator.summary()

# discriminative model

discriminator = Sequential()

discriminator.add(Convolution2D(64, 5, 5, subsample=(2, 2), border_mode='same', dim_ordering='th', input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]))
discriminator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))


discriminator.add(Convolution2D(128, 5, 5, subsample=(2, 2), border_mode='same', dim_ordering='th'))
discriminator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))


discriminator.add(Convolution2D(256, 5, 5, subsample=(2, 2), border_mode='same', dim_ordering='th'))
discriminator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))

discriminator.add(Convolution2D(512, 5, 5, subsample=(2, 2), border_mode='same', dim_ordering='th'))
discriminator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))

discriminator.add(Flatten())

discriminator.add(Dense(1024))
discriminator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
discriminator.add(Dropout(0.5))

discriminator.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

discriminator.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5))
discriminator.summary()

# GAN Model
gan_input = Input(shape=(100,))
gan_output = discriminator(generator(gan_input))
gan_model = Model(gan_input, gan_output)

gan_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5))
gan_model.summary()
print("Pre-training generator...")
noise_gen = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(14000, 100))   # at (0,1) creates 10000 points
generated_images = generator.predict(noise_gen)

print('generated_images shape ----', generated_images.shape)

X = np.concatenate((X_train[:14000, :, :, :], generated_images))
y = np.zeros([28000, 2])
y[:14000, 1] = 1
y[14000:, 0] = 1

discriminator.fit(X, y, nb_epoch=1, batch_size=128)
y_hat = discriminator.predict(X)

# set up loss storage vector
losses = {"d": [], "g": []}


def train_for_n(nb_epoch=28000, batch_size=128):
    for e in range(nb_epoch):

        # Make generative images
        train_idx = np.random.randint(0, X_train.shape[0], size=batch_size)  # 0 <= train_idx <= X_train.shape[0]
        mini_batch = X_train[train_idx]
        noise_gen = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(batch_size, 100))
        generated_images = generator.predict(noise_gen)

        # Train discriminator on generated images
        X = np.concatenate((mini_batch, generated_images))
        y = np.zeros([2 * batch_size, 2])
        y[:batch_size, 1] = 1
        y[batch_size:, 0] = 1

        discriminator.trainable = True
        for layer in discriminator.layers:
            layer.trainable = True
        d_loss = discriminator.train_on_batch(X, y)
        losses["d"].append(d_loss)

        noise_tr = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(batch_size, 100))
        y2 = np.zeros([batch_size, 2])
        y2[:, 1] = 1

        discriminator.trainable = False
        for layer in discriminator.layers:
            layer.trainable = False
        g_loss = gan_model.train_on_batch(noise_tr, y2)
        losses["g"].append(g_loss)

        if e % 10 == 9:
            generator.save_weights('G0_weights.h5')
            discriminator.save_weights('D0_weights.h5')
            noise = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(100, 100))
            generated_images = generator.predict(noise)
            np.save('/Users/zhangguanghua/Desktop/Stampede/generated_images_0.npy', generated_images)

        print(("Iteration: {0} / {1}, G-Loss: {2:.4f}".format(e, nb_epoch, float(g_loss))))


train_for_n(nb_epoch=2000, batch_size=128)
```

Additionally, Does someone know what is Inputs shapes: [(32, 8, 16, 1024), (256, 512, 5, 5)] stands for? How could I fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Could you add a gan_model.summary() result to your post?

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. What do u mean by adding a gan_model.summary()result? I don't understand. Thanks

Comment: this function prints the summary of your project. It should print it's topology

Comment: It's too long and I added the summary() result on the Answer.

Comment: Could you check the dim_ordering in Keras.json?

Comment: I have tried both "th" and "tf", however, it doesn't work either.

Comment: But have you tried to change it in json file?

Comment: I don't know how to change it in json file on stampede(the super computer), could you help me with this? Thanks so much!

Comment: What os do you have?

Comment: I use mac OS, I am thinking about whether I should define : os.environ['KERAS_IMAGE_DIM_ORDERING']='th' before I import keras.

Comment: Just tried to define                os.environ['KERAS_IMAGE_DIM_ORDERING']='th' before import keras, however, it doesn't work. It makes me crazy...

Comment: Look for keras.json on your drive. Open it and change it there.

Comment: I have changed it from the json file on my laptop, however, I can't change it from keras.json on Stampede. I don't know how to change it.

Answer (score 1):

When I run this code on cpu, the gan_model.summary() result is :
0.0 1.0
X_train shape ---  (29404, 3, 64, 64)
29404 train samples

---

```
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)                  (None, 16384)         1654784     dense_input_1[0][0]              
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
batchnormalization_1 (BatchNorma (None, 16384)         65536       dense_1[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)        (None, 16384)         0           batchnormalization_1[0][0]       
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
reshape_1 (Reshape)              (None, 1024, 4, 4)    0           activation_1[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
upsampling2d_1 (UpSampling2D)    (None, 1024, 8, 8)    0           reshape_1[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_1 (Convolution2D)  (None, 512, 8, 8)     13107712    upsampling2d_1[0][0]             
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
batchnormalization_2 (BatchNorma (None, 512, 8, 8)     32          convolution2d_1[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)        (None, 512, 8, 8)     0           batchnormalization_2[0][0]       
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
upsampling2d_2 (UpSampling2D)    (None, 512, 16, 16)   0           activation_2[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_2 (Convolution2D)  (None, 256, 16, 16)   3277056     upsampling2d_2[0][0]             
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
batchnormalization_3 (BatchNorma (None, 256, 16, 16)   64          convolution2d_2[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)        (None, 256, 16, 16)   0           batchnormalization_3[0][0]       
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
upsampling2d_3 (UpSampling2D)    (None, 256, 32, 32)   0           activation_3[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_3 (Convolution2D)  (None, 128, 32, 32)   819328      upsampling2d_3[0][0]             
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
batchnormalization_4 (BatchNorma (None, 128, 32, 32)   128         convolution2d_3[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)        (None, 128, 32, 32)   0           batchnormalization_4[0][0]       
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
upsampling2d_4 (UpSampling2D)    (None, 128, 64, 64)   0           activation_4[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_4 (Convolution2D)  (None, 64, 64, 64)    204864      upsampling2d_4[0][0]             
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
batchnormalization_5 (BatchNorma (None, 64, 64, 64)    256         convolution2d_4[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)        (None, 64, 64, 64)    0           batchnormalization_5[0][0]       
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_5 (Convolution2D)  (None, 3, 64, 64)     4803        activation_5[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_6 (Activation)        (None, 3, 64, 64)     0           convolution2d_5[0][0]            
====================================================================================================
Total params: 19,134,563
Trainable params: 19,101,555
Non-trainable params: 33,008
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
convolution2d_6 (Convolution2D)  (None, 64, 32, 32)    4864        convolution2d_input_1[0][0]      
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
leakyrelu_1 (LeakyReLU)          (None, 64, 32, 32)    0           convolution2d_6[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_7 (Convolution2D)  (None, 128, 16, 16)   204928      leakyrelu_1[0][0]                
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
leakyrelu_2 (LeakyReLU)          (None, 128, 16, 16)   0           convolution2d_7[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_8 (Convolution2D)  (None, 256, 8, 8)     819456      leakyrelu_2[0][0]                
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
leakyrelu_3 (LeakyReLU)          (None, 256, 8, 8)     0           convolution2d_8[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_9 (Convolution2D)  (None, 512, 4, 4)     3277312     leakyrelu_3[0][0]                
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
leakyrelu_4 (LeakyReLU)          (None, 512, 4, 4)     0           convolution2d_9[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)              (None, 8192)          0           leakyrelu_4[0][0]                
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                  (None, 1024)          8389632     flatten_1[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
leakyrelu_5 (LeakyReLU)          (None, 1024)          0           dense_2[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)              (None, 1024)          0           leakyrelu_5[0][0]                
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                  (None, 2)             2050        dropout_1[0][0]                  
====================================================================================================
Total params: 12,698,242
Trainable params: 12,698,242
Non-trainable params: 0
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)             (None, 100)           0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential_1 (Sequential)        (None, 3, 64, 64)     19134563    input_2[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential_2 (Sequential)        (None, 2)             12698242    sequential_1[1][0]               
====================================================================================================
Total params: 31,832,805
Trainable params: 31,799,797
Non-trainable params: 33,008
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Pre-training generator...
```

Comment: Problem solved. Just update keras and theano on stampede. The old version of Keras lets this problem.